# chartjs not working php page but working on html page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using chartjs charts on my web page. it is working properly on html page. but when I load them to server in php page it did not show any graph there. 
I have two graphs one is line and another is bar with following code.

```
var dData = function() {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * 90) + 10
};

var barChartData = {
  labels: ["dD 1", "dD 2", "dD 3", "dD 4", "dD 5", "dD 6", "dD 7", "dD 8", "dD 9", "dD 10"],
  datasets: [{
    fillColor: "rgba(102, 191, 255, 0.6)",
    strokeColor: "#07c",
    data: [dData(), dData(), dData(), dData(), dData(), dData(), dData(), dData(), dData(), dData()]
  }]
}

var index = 11;
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var barChartDemo = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
  responsive: true,
  barValueSpacing: 2
});




   var lineChartData = {
    labels: ["Date 1", "Date 2", "Date 3", "Date 4", "Date 5", "Date 6", "Date 7"],
    datasets: [ {
        fillColor: "rgba(102, 191, 255, 0.6)",
        strokeColor: "#07c",
        pointColor: "#0095ff",
        data: [60, 10, 40, 30, 80, 30, 20]
    }]

}

Chart.defaults.global.animationSteps = 50;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipYPadding = 16;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipCornerRadius = 0;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipTitleFontStyle = "normal";
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipFillColor = "black";
Chart.defaults.global.animationEasing = "easeOutBounce";
Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
Chart.defaults.global.scaleLineColor = "silver";
Chart.defaults.global.scaleFontSize = 16;

var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");
var LineChartDemo = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
    pointDotRadius: 10,
    bezierCurve: false,
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    scaleGridLineColor: "silver"
});
```

This is working very fine on local page in html. 
Following is js file I am using for it.

```
<script src="http://prosport.guru/ps/assets/js/charts.js"></script>
```

Html code to display graphs

```
<div class="row match-height">
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-12" style="padding:0px">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="">
                  <div style="width: 100%">
                    <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-12"  style="padding:0px">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div style="width: 100%">
                    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In console it shows this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the error, I think the following line of code fails to find any HTML element with id "canvas":

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
```

Can you check if your PHP code render the HTML element `<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>` correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is your js runs before the HTML is loaded.
Or simply put your js after the .
This is will work.